# Como ler os dados do JSON enviado pelo javascript no PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Quero passar um form via json pro meu php pra então inserir no bd os dados.

```
function enviaDados(form){
    var dados = document.getElementById('form');
    console.log(dados.categoria.value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "teste do json mo louco",
        url: "includes/post.php",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(dados.categoria.value);
        }
    });
    alert("sadfdsaf");
}
```

Como faço para ler esse json no meu php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recuperar os dados do seu formulário, você pode usar a função `serialize()`. Segue abaixo um exemplo de como usar:

```
function enviaDados(form){
    var dados = document.getElementById('form');
    console.log(dados.categoria.value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        url: "includes/post.php",
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(dados.categoria.value);
        }
    });
    alert("sadfdsaf");
}
```

Esse função vai pegar todos os valores do seu formulário e montar uma estrutura `chave` `valor`, onde a chave é o atributo name do `<inputs>`

no seu script PHP você vai recuperar os valores usando a super global $_POST. Vamos a um exemplo. Suponha que você tenha o seguinte formulário:

```
<form  method="post" id="myForm">
    Seu nome: <input type="text" name="nome">
</form>
```

No php você poderia recuperar a informação digitada no campo nome da seguinte forma:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
```

Comment: isso que eu precisava, me deu uma boa ideia. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver esperando uma string:
$string = [file_get_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php)('php://input');

Se você estiver esperando um objeto use o [json_decode](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).